# Help with saving or adding more than 4000 words to a List<T> in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, list

I need help with my application where i save a bunch of words like more than 4000 words or more in a List<[class name]>.

My problem is, as the number of words increases, the process in saving it in the list seems to go slower and the application uses a lot more of memory. 
 Can you give me an advise or alternative to do this without affecting the speed of the process?

Comment: 4000 words is very trivial for today's hardware. Are you saying that this takes a noticable amount of time to save this many words on a hard disk? Post more details about the code you are using to save the data.

Comment: Have you not thought of serializing the list and gzipping the binary data before writing it out? How are you saving it...? Code please?

Comment: i can't post the code but here's the idea.. I scan and compare n times of sites to view duplicate content. I'm saving the duplicate words or contents in the list for future use. As i scan, duplicate content increases more than 4000 words or more and this changes the speed of the comparison process and this uses alot of memory and often causes my app to hang. is there posible way to optimize or better solution?

Comment: not without seeing your code or at least a description of your comparison algorithm.

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as "C#.NET". There's VB.NET and C#.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you're doing lots of searches through your list and finding things slow down as the list grows. I think you want a `Dictionary` instead of a `List`. Instead of adding elements to the list, you would use those values as keys in the dictionary (you can use `null` as the values).